# dealing with stringstream in C++

Tags: c++, stream, c++17, std

i am reverting back to cpp after long years i have not been using it at all. i am trying to stay up date whilst refreshing my memories with correct practices and syntax, so i prefer the answers to be leaned towards cpp 17 onward(though 20 is not out yet).

so my situation is like this, assuming i have a stringstream object, i want to find an efficient way to convert its contents into upper/lower case. then i'll play with it(each even char in the string, etc). however, as far as i remember, unlike other programming languages, in c++ ::toupper/lower is done on chars, so i think it means i need to use std::transform on this container.

if you could regard the following questions while answering it would be great and allow me to capture multiple birds with one net, or something like this:

1. is it possible to do this with a for_each?
2. is it possible to use string_view and then refer to it to do the operations on it if i don't want to create a new string object to do the case manipulation?
3. are there any iterators for stringstream object? (like begin(),end() etc)
4. so what's the best way to do implement case change here?
5. is it possible to do this somehow without converting this to string, but rather manipulating it manually or is it path for trouble?

here's what i tried and failed ungracefuly with:

```
int main() {
    std::stringstream beginnersmistake;
    beginnersmistake<<"learning"<< " " << "to"<< "program" <<'\n';
    std::function<std::stringstream> ttoupper = [&beginnersmistake](){
        std::string stemp = beginnersmistake.str();
        std::transform(stemp.begin(),stemp.end(),stemp.begin(),::toupper);
    };
    std::cout<<"voila! a mistake comming:" << ttoupper;
    beginnersmistake.clear();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

thank you very much for helping a noobie joining the site :)

Comment: `std::stringstream` is not a container. The best way about this is to use both flavours of the [`std::stringstream::str`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str) member function

Comment: How much long is your input stringstream?

Comment: @Mannoj for instance a simple sentence. just trying to convert a stringstream uppercase

Comment: Basic question is why std::stringstream used here? as it's heavier than std::string. It's easier to use std::transform on std::string. Performance is good. You can take our string out of stringstream and operate on it

Comment: std::string inputString("beginners mistake");
    std::transform(inputString.begin(), inputString.end(), inputString.begin(), ::toupper);
    std::cout << inputString << std::endl;